# Layout issues after changing to link the styles content. Why?

Tags: html, css

I am completely confused. :(

Here is my HTML file. In this case I have the CSS styles all embedded in the document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>CONGREGATION NAME</title>
<style type="text/css">
/* Column widths */
.columnTime{
    width:7%;
}
.columnTheme1Class {
    width: 76%;
}
.columnTheme2Classes {
    width: 64%;
}
.columnTheme3Classes {
    width: 52%;
}
.columnName {
    width: 17%;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
table th, td {
    /* Comment out the following line if you do not want borders */
    border: 1px #d3d3d3 solid;
    /* This is the default font for all cells */
    font-family: Calibri;
}
table tbody tr:hover td {
    color: #000;
    background: #efefef;
}
.cellBibleReading {
    padding-left: 3mm;
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.cellTime {
    padding-left: 3mm;
    padding-right: 5mm;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: gray;
}
.cellName {
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.floatRight {
    color: gray;
    padding-top: 1mm;
    padding-bottom: 1mm;
    padding-right: 2mm;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: none;
}
.tableHEADINGOuter {
    border-top-style: none;
    border-left-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-bottom: 1px gray solid;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 5mm;
}
.tableHEADING {
}
.tableHEADING td {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-left-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-bottom: 4px gray solid;
}
.tableDATE {
    margin-bottom: 2mm;
}
.tableTFGW {
    margin-bottom: 2mm;
}
.cellTFGW {
    padding-left: 1mm;
}
.textTFGW {
    padding-left: 1mm;
    padding-top: 1mm;
    padding-bottom: 1mm;
    background-color: #606a70;
    width: 90mm;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.bulletTFGW {
    padding-top: 1mm;
    padding-bottom: 1mm;
    padding-right: 1mm;
    color: #606a70;
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.tableAYFM {
    margin-bottom: 2mm;
}
.cellAYFM {
    padding-left: 1mm;
}
.textAYFM {
    padding-left: 1mm;
    padding-top: 1mm;
    padding-bottom: 1mm;
    background-color: #c18626;
    width: 90mm;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.bulletAYFM {
    padding-top: 1mm;
    padding-bottom: 1mm;
    padding-right: 1mm;
    color: #c18626;
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.cellClass {
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-weight: 700;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    color: gray;
}
.tableLAC {
    margin-bottom: 2mm;
}
.cellLAC {
    padding-left: 1mm;
}
.textLAC {
    padding-left: 1mm;
    padding-top: 1mm;
    padding-bottom: 1mm;
    background-color: #961526;
    width: 90mm;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.bulletLAC {
    padding-top: 1mm;
    padding-bottom: 1mm;
    padding-right: 1mm;
    color: #961526;
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.textDuration {
    padding-left: 1mm;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.textTheme {
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.textSongLabel {
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.textSongNumber {
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.textCongregation {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.textTitle {
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-weight: 700;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="tableHEADINGOuter">
    <table class="tableHEADING">
        <colgroup>
            <col width="50%" /><col width="50%" />
        </colgroup>
        <tr>
            <td class="textCongregation">CONGREGATION NAME</td>
            <td class="textTitle">Midweek Meeting Schedule</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<table class="tableDATE">
    <colgroup>
        <col class="columnTime" /><col class="columnTheme1Class" />
        <col class="columnName" />
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellBibleReading" colspan="2">
        <div class="floatRight">
            Chairman:<br />
            Auxiliary Classroom Counselor 1: </div>
        April 11-17&nbsp;|&nbsp;Job 21-27</td>
        <td class="cellName">Chairman<br />
        Chairman Class 1<br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellTime">19:20</td>
        <td>
        <div class="floatRight">
            Prayer: </div>
        <span class="bulletTFGW">•</span> <span class="textSongLabel">Song</span>
        <span class="textSongNumber">83</span> </td>
        <td class="cellName">Brother 0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellTime">19:23</td>
        <td class="textTheme"><span class="bulletTFGW">•</span>
        <span class="textTheme">Opening Comments</span>
        <span class="textDuration">(3 min.) </span></td>
        <td class="cellName">Chairman</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="tableHEADINGOuter">
    <table class="tableHEADING">
        <colgroup>
            <col width="50%" /><col width="50%" />
        </colgroup>
        <tr>
            <td class="textCongregation">CONGREGATION NAME</td>
            <td class="textTitle">Midweek Meeting Schedule</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<table class="tableDATE">
    <colgroup>
        <col class="columnTime" /><col class="columnTheme1Class" />
        <col class="columnName" />
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellBibleReading" colspan="2">
        <div class="floatRight">
            Chairman:<br />
            Auxiliary Classroom Counselor 1:<br />
            Auxiliary Classroom Counselor 2: </div>
        April 11-17&nbsp;|&nbsp;Job 21-27</td>
        <td class="cellName">Chairman<br />
        Chairman Class 1<br />
        Chairman Class 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellTime">19:20</td>
        <td>
        <div class="floatRight">
            Prayer: </div>
        <span class="bulletTFGW">•</span> <span class="textSongLabel">Song</span>
        <span class="textSongNumber">83</span> </td>
        <td class="cellName">Brother 0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellTime">19:23</td>
        <td class="textTheme"><span class="bulletTFGW">•</span>
        <span class="textTheme">Opening Comments</span>
        <span class="textDuration">(3 min.) </span></td>
        <td class="cellName">Chairman</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="tableHEADINGOuter">
    <table class="tableHEADING">
        <colgroup>
            <col width="50%" /><col width="50%" />
        </colgroup>
        <tr>
            <td class="textCongregation">CONGREGATION NAME</td>
            <td class="textTitle">Midweek Meeting Schedule</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<table class="tableDATE">
    <colgroup>
        <col class="columnTime" /><col class="columnTheme1Class" />
        <col class="columnName" />
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellBibleReading" colspan="2">
        <div class="floatRight">
            Chairman: </div>
        April 11-17&nbsp;|&nbsp;Job 21-27</td>
        <td class="cellName">Chairman<br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellTime">19:20</td>
        <td>
        <div class="floatRight">
            Prayer: </div>
        <span class="bulletTFGW">•</span> <span class="textSongLabel">Song</span>
        <span class="textSongNumber">83</span> </td>
        <td class="cellName">Brother 0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellTime">19:23</td>
        <td class="textTheme"><span class="bulletTFGW">•</span>
        <span class="textTheme">Opening Comments</span>
        <span class="textDuration">(3 min.) </span></td>
        <td class="cellName">Chairman</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="tableTFGW">
    <colgroup>
        <col class="columnTime" /><col class="columnTheme1Class" />
        <col class="columnName" />
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellTFGW" colspan="2">
        <div class="textTFGW">
            TREASURES FROM GOD'S WORD </div>
        </td>
        <td class="cellClass">Main Hall</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellTime">19:33</td>
        <td colspan="1"><span class="bulletTFGW">•</span>
        <span class="textTheme">Theme 1</span> <span class="textDuration">(10 min.)
        </span></td>
        <td class="cellName">Brother 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellTime">19:41</td>
        <td colspan="1"><span class="bulletTFGW">•</span>
        <span class="textTheme">Digging for Spiritual Gems</span>
        <span class="textDuration">(8 min.) </span></td>
        <td class="cellName">Brother 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellTime">19:46</td>
        <td>
        <div class="floatRight">
            Student: </div>
        <span class="bulletTFGW">•</span> <span class="textTheme">Bible Reading</span>
        <span class="textDuration">(4 min. or less) </span></td>
        <td class="cellName">ReaderM</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="tableTFGW">
    <colgroup>
        <col class="columnTime" /><col class="columnTheme2Class" />
        <col class="columnName" /><col class="columnName" />
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellTFGW" colspan="2">
        <div class="textTFGW">
            TREASURES FROM GOD'S WORD </div>
        </td>
        <td class="cellClass">Auxiliary Classroom 1</td>
        <td class="cellClass">Main Hall</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellTime">19:33</td>
        <td colspan="2"><span class="bulletTFGW">•</span>
        <span class="textTheme">Theme 1</span> <span class="textDuration">(10 min.)
        </span></td>
        <td class="cellName">Brother 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellTime">19:41</td>
        <td colspan="2"><span class="bulletTFGW">•</span>
        <span class="textTheme">Digging for Spiritual Gems</span>
        <span class="textDuration">(8 min.) </span></td>
        <td class="cellName">Brother 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellTime">19:46</td>
        <td>
        <div class="floatRight">
            Student: </div>
        <span class="bulletTFGW">•</span> <span class="textTheme">Bible Reading</span>
        <span class="textDuration">(4 min. or less) </span></td>
        <td class="cellName">Reader1</td>
        <td class="cellName">ReaderM</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="tableTFGW">
    <colgroup>
        <col class="columnTime" /><col class="columnTheme3Class" />
        <col class="columnName" /><col class="columnName" />
        <col class="columnName" />
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellTFGW" colspan="2">
        <div class="textTFGW">
            TREASURES FROM GOD'S WORD </div>
        </td>
        <td class="cellClass">Auxiliary Classroom 1</td>
        <td class="cellClass">Auxiliary Classroom 2</td>
        <td class="cellClass">Main Hall</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellTime">19:33</td>
        <td colspan="3"><span class="bulletTFGW">•</span>
        <span class="textTheme">Theme 1</span> <span class="textDuration">(10 min.)
        </span></td>
        <td class="cellName">Brother 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellTime">19:41</td>
        <td colspan="3"><span class="bulletTFGW">•</span>
        <span class="textTheme">Digging for Spiritual Gems</span>
        <span class="textDuration">(8 min.) </span></td>
        <td class="cellName">Brother 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellTime">19:46</td>
        <td>
        <div class="floatRight">
            Student: </div>
        <span class="bulletTFGW">•</span> <span class="textTheme">Bible Reading</span>
        <span class="textDuration">(4 min. or less) </span></td>
        <td class="cellName">Reader1</td>
        <td class="cellName">Reader2</td>
        <td class="cellName">ReaderM</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="tableAYFM">
    <colgroup>
        <col class="columnTime" /><col class="columnTheme1Class" />
        <col class="columnName" />
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellAYFM" colspan="2">
        <div class="textAYFM">
            APPLY YOURSELF TO THE FIELD MINISTRY </div>
        </td>
        <td class="cellClass">Main Hall</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellTime">20:02</td>
        <td><span class="bulletAYFM">•</span> <span class="textTheme">Prepare This 
        Month’s Presentations</span> <span class="textDuration">(15 min.) </span>
        </td>
        <td class="cellName">Brother 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="tableAYFM">
    <colgroup>
        <col class="columnTime" /><col class="columnTheme1Class" />
        <col class="columnName" />
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellAYFM" colspan="2">
        <div class="textAYFM">
            APPLY YOURSELF TO THE FIELD MINISTRY </div>
        </td>
        <td class="cellClass">Main Hall</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellTime">19:49</td>
        <td>
        <div class="floatRight">
            Student:<br />
            Assistant: </div>
        <span class="bulletAYFM">•</span> <span class="textTheme">Initial Call</span>
        <span class="textDuration">(2 min. or less) </span></td>
        <td class="cellName">Name1M<br />
        Name1MA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellTime">19:54</td>
        <td>
        <div class="floatRight">
            Student:<br />
            Assistant: </div>
        <span class="bulletAYFM">•</span> <span class="textTheme">Return Visit</span>
        <span class="textDuration">(4 min. or less) </span></td>
        <td class="cellName">Name2M<br />
        Name2MA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellTime">20:01</td>
        <td>
        <div class="floatRight">
            Student:<br />
            Assistant: </div>
        <span class="bulletAYFM">•</span> <span class="textTheme">Bible Study</span>
        <span class="textDuration">(6 min. or less) </span></td>
        <td class="cellName">Name3M<br />
        Name3MA</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="tableHEADINGOuter">
    <table class="tableHEADING">
        <colgroup>
            <col width="50%" /><col width="50%" />
        </colgroup>
        <tr>
            <td class="textCongregation">CONGREGATION NAME</td>
            <td class="textTitle">Midweek Meeting Schedule</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<table class="tableDATE">
    <colgroup>
        <col class="columnTime" /><col class="columnTheme1Class" />
        <col class="columnName" />
    </colgroup>
</table>
<table class="tableAYFM">
    <colgroup>
        <col class="columnTime" /><col class="columnTheme2Class" />
        <col class="columnName" /><col class="columnName" />
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellAYFM" colspan="2">
        <div class="textAYFM">
            APPLY YOURSELF TO THE FIELD MINISTRY </div>
        </td>
        <td class="cellClass">Auxiliary Classroom 1</td>
        <td class="cellClass">Main Hall</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellTime">19:49</td>
        <td>
        <div class="floatRight">
            Student:<br />
            Assistant: </div>
        <span class="bulletAYFM">•</span> <span class="textTheme">Initial Call</span>
        <span class="textDuration">(2 min. or less) </span></td>
        <td class="cellName">Name11<br />
        Name11A</td>
        <td class="cellName">Name1M<br />
        Name1MA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellTime">19:54</td>
        <td>
        <div class="floatRight">
            Student:<br />
            Assistant: </div>
        <span class="bulletAYFM">•</span> <span class="textTheme">Return Visit</span>
        <span class="textDuration">(4 min. or less) </span></td>
        <td class="cellName">Name21<br />
        Name21A</td>
        <td class="cellName">Name2M<br />
        Name2MA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellTime">20:01</td>
        <td>
        <div class="floatRight">
            Student:<br />
            Assistant: </div>
        <span class="bulletAYFM">•</span> <span class="textTheme">Bible Study</span>
        <span class="textDuration">(6 min. or less) </span></td>
        <td class="cellName">Name31<br />
        Name31A</td>
        <td class="cellName">Name3M<br />
        Name3MA</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="tableHEADINGOuter">
    <table class="tableHEADING">
        <colgroup>
            <col width="50%" /><col width="50%" />
        </colgroup>
        <tr>
            <td class="textCongregation">CONGREGATION NAME</td>
            <td class="textTitle">Midweek Meeting Schedule</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<table class="tableDATE">
    <colgroup>
        <col class="columnTime" /><col class="columnTheme1Class" />
        <col class="columnName" />
    </colgroup>
</table>
<table class="tableAYFM">
    <colgroup>
        <col class="columnTime" /><col class="columnTheme3Class" />
        <col class="columnName" /><col class="columnName" />
        <col class="columnName" />
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellAYFM" colspan="2">
        <div class="textAYFM">
            APPLY YOURSELF TO THE FIELD MINISTRY </div>
        </td>
        <td class="cellClass">Auxiliary Classroom 1</td>
        <td class="cellClass">Auxiliary Classroom 2</td>
        <td class="cellClass">Main Hall</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellTime">19:49</td>
        <td>
        <div class="floatRight">
            Student:<br />
            Assistant: </div>
        <span class="bulletAYFM">•</span> <span class="textTheme">Initial Call</span>
        <span class="textDuration">(2 min. or less) </span></td>
        <td class="cellName">Name11<br />
        Name11A</td>
        <td class="cellName">Name12<br />
        Name12A</td>
        <td class="cellName">Name1M<br />
        Name1MA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellTime">19:54</td>
        <td>
        <div class="floatRight">
            Student:<br />
            Assistant: </div>
        <span class="bulletAYFM">•</span> <span class="textTheme">Return Visit</span>
        <span class="textDuration">(4 min. or less) </span></td>
        <td class="cellName">Name21<br />
        Name21A</td>
        <td class="cellName">Name22<br />
        Name22A</td>
        <td class="cellName">Name2M<br />
        Name2MA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellTime">20:01</td>
        <td>
        <div class="floatRight">
            Student:<br />
            Assistant: </div>
        <span class="bulletAYFM">•</span> <span class="textTheme">Bible Study</span>
        <span class="textDuration">(6 min. or less) </span></td>
        <td class="cellName">Name31<br />
        Name31A</td>
        <td class="cellName">Name32<br />
        Name32A</td>
        <td class="cellName">Name3M<br />
        Name3MA</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="tableLAC">
    <colgroup>
        <col class="columnTime" /><col class="columnTheme1Class" />
        <col class="columnName" />
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellLAC" colspan="3">
        <div class="textLAC">
            LIVING AS CHRISTIANS </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellTime">20:07</td>
        <td colspan="2"><span class="bulletLAC">•</span>
        <span class="textSongLabel">Song</span> <span class="textSongNumber">42</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellTime">20:17</td>
        <td><span class="bulletLAC">•</span> <span class="textTheme">Theme 1</span>
        <span class="textDuration">(10 min.) </span></td>
        <td class="cellName">Brother 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellTime">20:22</td>
        <td><span class="bulletLAC">•</span> <span class="textTheme">Theme 2</span>
        <span class="textDuration">(5 min.) </span></td>
        <td class="cellName">Brother 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellTime">20:52</td>
        <td>
        <div class="floatRight">
            Conductor:<br />
            Reader: </div>
        <span class="bulletLAC">•</span> <span class="textTheme">Congregation Bible 
        Study </span><span class="textDuration">(30 min.)</span> </td>
        <td class="cellName">Conductor<br />
        Reader</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellTime">20:55</td>
        <td class="textTheme"><span class="bulletLAC">•</span>
        <span class="textTheme">Review/Preview/Announcements</span>
        <span class="textDuration">(3 min.) </span></td>
        <td class="cellName">Chairman</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellTime">21:00</td>
        <td>
        <div class="floatRight">
            Prayer: </div>
        <span class="bulletLAC">•</span> <span class="textSongLabel">Song</span>
        <span class="textSongNumber">65</span> </td>
        <td class="cellName">Brother 8</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="tableLAC">
    <colgroup>
        <col class="columnTime" /><col class="columnTheme1Class" />
        <col class="columnName" />
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellLAC" colspan="3">
        <div class="textLAC">
            LIVING AS CHRISTIANS </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellTime">20:07</td>
        <td colspan="2"><span class="bulletLAC">•</span>
        <span class="textSongLabel">Song</span> <span class="textSongNumber">42</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellTime">20:17</td>
        <td><span class="bulletLAC">•</span> <span class="textTheme">Theme 1</span>
        <span class="textDuration">(10 min.) </span></td>
        <td class="cellName">Brother 4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellTime">20:22</td>
        <td><span class="bulletLAC">•</span> <span class="textTheme">Theme 2</span>
        <span class="textDuration">(5 min.) </span></td>
        <td class="cellName">Brother 5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellTime">20:25</td>
        <td class="textTheme"><span class="bulletLAC">•</span>
        <span class="textTheme">Review/Preview/Announcements</span>
        <span class="textDuration">(3 min.) </span></td>
        <td class="cellName">Chairman</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellTime">20:55</td>
        <td><span class="bulletLAC">•</span> <span class="textTheme">Service Talk 
        Theme</span> <span class="textDuration">(30 min.) </span></td>
        <td class="cellName">Circuit Overseer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="cellTime">21:00</td>
        <td>
        <div class="floatRight">
            Prayer: </div>
        <span class="bulletLAC">•</span> <span class="textSongLabel">Song</span>
        <span class="textSongNumber">65</span> </td>
        <td class="cellName">Brother 8</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

It works fine. See that the columns are all aligned:

[image: Internal CSS styles]

So, I decided I would move the styles into their own CSS document (not included to keep topic under 30000 characters). Fairly normal stuff to do. And thus I changed the HTML to link this CSS document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<link href="WEEK-S-140.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

In effect, the results should be exactly the same. But look:

[image: External styling]

All the column sizes are messed up. Why is this? If I go back to embedding the styles, all good. Move it out into a CSS and link, all funny. I am using Internet Explorer.

Thank you for your advice on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please open your  WEEK-S-140.css in editor and replace with the code below:

```
/* Column widths */
.columnTime{
    width:7%;
}
.columnTheme1Class {
    width: 76%;
}
.columnTheme2Classes {
    width: 64%;
}
.columnTheme3Classes {
    width: 52%;
}
.columnName {
    width: 17%;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
table th, td {
    /* Comment out the following line if you do not want borders */
    border: 1px #d3d3d3 solid;
    /* This is the default font for all cells */
    font-family: Calibri;
}
table tbody tr:hover td {
    color: #000;
    background: #efefef;
}
.cellBibleReading {
    padding-left: 3mm;
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.cellTime {
    padding-left: 3mm;
    padding-right: 5mm;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: gray;
}
.cellName {
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.floatRight {
    color: gray;
    padding-top: 1mm;
    padding-bottom: 1mm;
    padding-right: 2mm;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: none;
}
.tableHEADINGOuter {
    border-top-style: none;
    border-left-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-bottom: 1px gray solid;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 5mm;
}
.tableHEADING {
}
.tableHEADING td {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-left-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-bottom: 4px gray solid;
}
.tableDATE {
    margin-bottom: 2mm;
}
.tableTFGW {
    margin-bottom: 2mm;
}
.cellTFGW {
    padding-left: 1mm;
}
.textTFGW {
    padding-left: 1mm;
    padding-top: 1mm;
    padding-bottom: 1mm;
    background-color: #606a70;
    width: 90mm;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.bulletTFGW {
    padding-top: 1mm;
    padding-bottom: 1mm;
    padding-right: 1mm;
    color: #606a70;
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.tableAYFM {
    margin-bottom: 2mm;
}
.cellAYFM {
    padding-left: 1mm;
}
.textAYFM {
    padding-left: 1mm;
    padding-top: 1mm;
    padding-bottom: 1mm;
    background-color: #c18626;
    width: 90mm;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.bulletAYFM {
    padding-top: 1mm;
    padding-bottom: 1mm;
    padding-right: 1mm;
    color: #c18626;
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.cellClass {
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-weight: 700;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    color: gray;
}
.tableLAC {
    margin-bottom: 2mm;
}
.cellLAC {
    padding-left: 1mm;
}
.textLAC {
    padding-left: 1mm;
    padding-top: 1mm;
    padding-bottom: 1mm;
    background-color: #961526;
    width: 90mm;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.bulletLAC {
    padding-top: 1mm;
    padding-bottom: 1mm;
    padding-right: 1mm;
    color: #961526;
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.textDuration {
    padding-left: 1mm;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.textTheme {
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.textSongLabel {
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.textSongNumber {
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.textCongregation {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-weight: 700;
}
.textTitle {
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am afraid that the results seem to be exactly the same.

Comment: can you paste your external css here..so that i can have a look..because for me it is coming fine when i am linking to external css

Comment: I just shared it via dropbox.

Comment: Ah, I see, I should not have the <style>....</style> wrappers in the CSS file. That fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if you have multiple css files linked to your HTML Document, then link the current css file at the last.
Like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<link href="WEEK-S-01.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="WEEK-S-02.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="WEEK-S-140.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Hi. I do not have multiple link references. I moved the internal <style> block out of the HTML file into an external CSS document and linked it. I have one link reference. You can replicate the issue by extracting the CSS content into a file and adjusting the HTML to link to it. Compare the results.